# Laravel, how to i catch a request that is sent back to me

Tags: php, json, laravel, request

i would like to know how to a catch a request that is sent back. I can send the stuff that i need but cant catch the answer that is sent back to me.

it is coming in like this.

```
Request URL: https://myserver/index.php/response/stuff/success/26?json=allthedatathatiscoimin
```

I need to catch the request and then save it to sql, i can save and everything just dont know how to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use laravel Request to catch your request.

I assume you have a controller method binded to your success route

```
public function success(Request $request)
{
 if($request->has('json')) 
 { 
    $json = $request->get('json'); // DO whatever you want with json key's value
 }
}
```

Comment: Just to avoid confusion.

i have routes like this for what i am useing.

Route::get('donate/{id}/{slug?}','DonationsController@show');
Route::post('donate/{id}','DonationsController@send');

Route::post('payment','DonationsController@maksekeskusReturn');

Route::get('payment/donation/success/{id}', function($id){
 session()->put('donation_success', trans('misc.donation_success'));
 return redirect("campaign/".$id);
});

And then also for cancel route

Comment: You want to capture the data at /payment/donation/success/{id} route ?

Comment: Yes, its payment link, it goes to payment provider and sends all the data that way correctly, but im not able to catch the return data to see if the payment was success or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel http client as document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) or use [guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html).

Below code may help you in using *laravel http client*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$address = 'https://myserver/index.php/response/stuff/success/26?json=allthedatathatiscoimin';

$request = Http::get($address);

if($request->ok()){
    $your_json_data = $request->json();

    $your_array_data = json_decode($your_json_data, true);

    $your_collected_data = collect($your_array_data);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but can use request without addres.
class DonationsController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct( AdminSettings $settings, Request $request) {
  $this->settings = $settings::first();
  $this->request = $request;
 }

Comment: I can't get your meaning. Are trying to get a json response from a foreign server/site?

Comment: First the data is sent to a forgein site, where the payment is processed(this part all works, it sends data and all is good)
Then the server will send data back in the way of the link it opens (Return to seller)
https://myserver/index.php/response/stuff/success/26?json=allthedatathatiscoimin